# How to update all the fields (same data-type) of a single record in one shot?

Tags: apex

I have a custom setting record which has more than 20 Checkbox fields. Is there a way to update all of the fields (*same type: checkbox*) at once?

I know I can do this:

```
My_Custom_Setting__c mcs = [SELECT checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, ..., checkbox20 FROM My_Custom_Setting__c LIMIT 1];
mcs.checkbox1 = true;
mcs.checkbox2 = true;
mcs.checkbox3 = true;
.
.
.
mcs.checkbox20 = true;
update msc;
```

I want to do something like this:

```
My_Custom_Setting__c mcs = [SELECT checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, ..., checkbox20 FROM My_Custom_Setting__c LIMIT 1];
Map<String, Object> valueMap = mcs[0].getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();

for(String fieldName : valueMap.keySet()){
   //fieldName will be checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, ..., checkbox20 for each iteration
   bypassAutomationSettings[0].set(fieldName,false);
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you almost had it. It's `.put`, rather than `.set`:

```
for(String fieldName : valueMap.keySet()){
   //fieldName will be checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, ..., checkbox20 for each iteration
   bypassAutomationSettings[0].put(fieldName,false);
}
```

However, you'll also have non-checkbox fields in the mix, so check first:

```
Map<String, sObjectField> fields = sObjectType.My_Custom_Setting__c .fields.getFields();
for(String fieldName : valueMap.keySet()){
   //fieldName will be checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, ..., checkbox20 for each iteration
   if(fields.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType() == DisplayType.BOOLEAN) {
     bypassAutomationSettings[0].put(fieldName,false);
   }
}
```

Comment: You da boss! That was it. Thank you!!